# How to prevent div inside of a row from increasing it's size? (screenshots)

Tags: html, css

The problem is that if a title is too long, it goes to the second line and it makes the whole post div bigger. Is there any way to prevent this behaviour?

I could use text-overflow:ellipsis but there's probably a better solution.

Thanks

up

```
       <div class="row">                   
        <div class="news-list">
          <article class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="image-holder">
              <img src="">
            </div>
            <h4><a href=""></a></h4>                 
              <time datetime=""></time> | <a href="#"> </a>    
            <p>excerpt</p>
          </article>
        </div>
```

so I'm just filling a row with divs

```
.news-list article {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 74px;
}

.col-sm-6 {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

---

Screens:

BEFORE screen resizing 
[image]

AFTER
[image]

Comment: Are you using float: left, or display: inline-block to position your divs?

Comment: updated the question. I'm using float left for the col

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you have to clear every 3rd div. Use this code snippet to achieve what you want.

```
.news-list article:nth-child(2n+1) { clear: both; }
```

This clears every third float, so it should fix your problem.

Comment: hey, that worked. But I used nth on .news-list only 
".news-list:nth-child(2n+1) { clear: both; }"
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to deal with this kind of grid design is to use **FlexBox**. it also gives you out of the box responsiveness.

**[FlexBox Guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)**

See the below example.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container .slide {
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
  padding: 5px;
}
.container .iImg {
  width: 100%;
}
.container .heading {
  color: rgb(190, 17, 47);
  font-size: smaller;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="slide">
    <img class="iImg" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/" />
    <h2 class="heading"> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</h2> 
    <p class="desc">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
      remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img class="iImg" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/2/" />
    <h2 class="heading"> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</h2> 
    <p class="desc">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
      remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img class="iImg" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/3/" />
    <h2 class="heading"> Lorem Ipsum is simply. </h2> 
    <p class="desc">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
      remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img class="iImg" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/4/" />
    <h2 class="heading"> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</h2> 
    <p class="desc">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img class="iImg" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/5/" />
    <h2 class="heading"> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</h2> 
    <p class="desc">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img class="iImg" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/6/" />
    <h2 class="heading"> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</h2> 
    <p class="desc">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
      remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img class="iImg" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/7/" />
    <h2 class="heading"> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</h2> 
    <p class="desc">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
      remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img class="iImg" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/8/" />
    <h2 class="heading"> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</h2> 
    <p class="desc">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
      remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img class="iImg" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/9/" />
    <h2 class="heading"> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</h2> 
    <p class="desc">Make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
      and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img class="iImg" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/2/" />
    <h2 class="heading"> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</h2> 
    <p class="desc">It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea but I'll stick with the current solution for now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use clear:right every 2nd item/column.

```
.column:nth-child(2n) {
clear:right;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using `overflow:hidden` with an absolute height for the div (eg. `height:200px` for instance)?

Edit:
To keep your title on one line, use `white-space: nowrap;`.

Edit2:
If you want to let the divs expand, but not create empty space on the row beneath, you could try using `vertical-align:top; display:inline-block;` on the divs, as demonstrated in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/16t50sj6/1/).

Comment: Fixed heights were never mentioned to be an option, and fixed heights are never a good idea.

Comment: He asked how to prevent it from increasing it's size and that's exactly what height or max-height does. However, he could also use white-space: nowrap; with overflow:hidden; if he wants the text to remain on one line.

Comment: Yes I tried that. The fixed height is not an option.

Comment: white-space: nowrap; with overflow:hidden;  will make the title go onto the right div.

Comment: Could you show some of your code, maybe create a fiddle? Also, what behaviour do you exactly want for it? Do you want everything to be visible including the long title, but avoid the empty space below the larger boxes?